# Node with webpack- "Cannot find module 'fs'" despite including target: node in webpac

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am using node.js and the webpack dev server to write a web app.  I am getting the error "cannot find module fs" and "Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'" errors.

**What I've tried:**

1. Setting `target : 'node'` (as seen below in my webpack config file)
2. Installing a package called nodeExternals to try to "force" webpack to recognize node code
3. Setting `node: { fs: "empty" }` in Webpack

I have searched through what seems like every other post with the same name but I can't seem to figure out what's going on and don't know enough about Webpack and how it interfaces with Node to know where to start here.

Webpack-config file:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body',    
    target: 'node',

});

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
    {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
      }
    }
        ]
    },
    externals: nodeModules,
  target: 'node',
externals: [nodeExternals()],

    output: {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
    devtool: "inline-source-map"
};
```

Import in index.js:

```
import * as fs from 'file-system';

//i've also tried before: 
//var fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: `target: 'node'` alone is enough to not get this problem. Double check that the config you posted is actually applied, i.e. you don't have any other config in effect.